# Css Breadcrumb Displaying Vertical Lines in IE and FF

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to copy this example for a bread crumb.
I love this bread crumb, but can't understand why the author didn't fix the lines in it.

I'm using Bootstrap 3.0:

I don't see the issue in Chrome 32, but IE 11 and FF 25 you can see the lines.

The link below has the HTML, CSS, and a display of the breadcrumb.

http://codepen.io/eMaj/pen/qtico

I haven't been successful at removing them.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I din't see what you mean in firefox.

Comment: I'm not sure what is different in our environments.  Are you using FF v. 26?  One thing I messed up on is in my web page you see the white background, but in the example that I copied it from the background is black.

Comment: Are you zoomed in on those browsers it's not working on?  Press 'Ctrl+0' and see if it makes a difference

Comment: In FF if I zoom in they disappear.  I'm trying to find out if I'm at a 100%. If so I'm ok with that.  Why does this happen?

Comment: Pressing 'Ctrl+0' will put you to 100%.  I'm not sure why these display issues happen when zooming, but it could be to do with the way browsers deal with rounding numbers.  Read the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835287/zoom-changes-the-design-layout

Comment: Thanks davidpauljunior, I appreciate your help.  It was a rounding issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some zoom scales the design gets broken because of pixel roundings.

Give the pseudo elements 1px aditional solves the issue in my browser

```
a{   
  &:before,
  &:after{
    content: "";
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    border:0 solid $blue;
    border-width:20px 11px;   /* original value 20px 10px */
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have checked it in FF and its looking okay to me, without any white border.
Try to clear your cache

Comment: I cleared my cache, but no luck. I also updated FF to version 26 and still no luck. I'm using Windows 8. But I don't know how that would affect it.